# android- image naming convention: How is the name generated?

Tags: android

I am curious about image naming convention on some android devices. For example, images taken on asus smartphone have names of the type

image-long string of letters and numbers-V

Does anyone know if this string contains any useful information or it's a random one?

thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the qualifiers used on folders to determine which resources to use? http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Answer (score 1):

There is no contract as to what a Camera application must name the photos that it saves. You certainly should not build around this expectation.

If you need useful information from an image, you should prefer the EXIF data (see the [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) class for more information about what’s available).